# How much French Press is a serving?

Tags: french-press, single-serving

I have a small cafetiere for making French Press coffee. I can't remember what it said on the box when I bought it - it's quite old - but it seems similar to those advertised as '2-cup' size.

Making coffee with it, filling it all the way up, makes a decent mugfull - what I'd consider enough for one person. Is this actually two 'servings' of french press? When I calculate how much caffeine I'm taking in, should I double the values given for French Press?

Comment: Generally speaking if you're looking at any sort of nutritional information, caffeine content and so on, the serving size will be included in the report. If it isn't, be suspicious of the source.

Comment: See [my answer](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/324/86) to my similar question wondering how much caffeine is in my typical serving from my small "2 cup" French Press.

Answer (score 3):

FDA has no official guidelines on serving size, so your serving size is either determined by the product manufacturer, or whatever you want it to be. We don't know what brand french press you have but if it was [Bodum](http://bodum.bodum.com/us/en-us/cms/552/102392/) for instance:

> Coffee is measured in 4 oz. cups, so our 3-cup press will brew 12 oz.; a single serving.

Answer (score 1):

12 oz (3-cup) would be it. For more info, this search query would help, http://goo.gl/jc6k6p.

Sourced from http://www.wisebread.com/