# How much caffeine delivered by eating coffee grounds

Tags: caffeine, ground-coffee

I eat coffee grounds.

I have size 000 capsules (just think of the size of the largest supplement capsules you may have seen), a capsule maker, and some Death Wish (which they tout as premium Ruousto, with "twice the caffeine" (that's their marketing line)) coffee, ground to regular drip coffee maker standards (as delivered by the company, to me).

I tamp the ground coffee into those capsules; it's pretty densely compacted.
Naturally, I get a bit more caffeine per quantity than as brewed (any method) or as would come from Arabica, but, how many milligrams per capsule, roughly?
Anyone able to venture a guess?

Comment: Hi Twonby, you can check https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/79/how-can-i-figure-out-how-much-caffeine-is-in-my-cup. @Nathan has a great answer to your question, there. All you need to do is to weight the coffee you ate.

Comment: Thanks. Will check. Indeed, problem is that I lack the scale that will accurately measure down to these minute quantities. Appreciate the suggestion/reference, though. As I am the proud possessor of nearly a kilo of 99.9% pure anhydrous caffeine, I may, at some point, get a scale that can measure down to the milligram.

Answer (score 1):

Well, eating coffee beans provides you with much more caffeine than drinking coffee. In comparison with the 95 milligrams in 1 cup of brewed coffee, a 28-bean serving of dark chocolate-covered coffee beans contains 336 milligrams of caffeine. So if your capsules could hold one bean, lets say, that would be roughly 12 milligrams of caffeine per bean.

Comment: Thank you. I've been guessing that each capsule - once you grind those beans - might encompass about a bean, each...just from a rough eye-balling of it, so that goes along with my prevailing theory. Thanks for answering. I also put matcha green tea into capsules...

Comment: If "Death Wish Cofffee" is, indeed, as their marketing line states (truly, it's just a property of the varietal, so, if one could purchase "premium" robusto (which is what they claim to use - in initial pricing (just poking around the internet, so, this wasn't extensive or when buying bulk) it seems to be about the same price - like $20 per pound - that Death Wish costs),  you should get the same double-the-caffeine outcome), "twice the caffeine," then I'd guess we're roughly able to double that milligram guesstimate, assuming you were thinking Arabica...